# AWS API - AmazonIdentityManagementService.GetUser - Username is null

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to get the name listed in my account details (Full Name) but this APIreturns userName as null; is there any other API that can get me this detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like none of the APIs return account full name at this point of time:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=54410&tstart=0